# Complex searching with ML.NET

Tags: search, ml.net

I am new to Machine Learning. Can we use this framework to simplify complex searching? What all things you should know if you want to do complex searching in ML.NET?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the use case that you are trying.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify one of the advanced search functionality we use in our system and make simpler using ML.NET. To explain a few points here, Managers have spent a lot of time and difficulties working on filtering users applied for certain projects. So, the system has UI features to allow the manger to build a list of criterias like 'Region LIKE 1, Project like 'PT12', ...' they want to filter the users. And then, the system will be rearranging the criteria and run to provide the result from the database. Is there a way to use ML.NET to simplify this complex searching?